# Python save string to list(Another File!)

Tags: python, string, list, save

Question is... How I can save value of (word) in used_words_list list which is in usedDB.py file.

```
from usedDB import used_words_list


def word_len(word):
 16 |  if len(word) <= 5:
 15 |   print("Not enough letters. Try again!")
 14 |  elif len(word) == 6 or len(word) == 7 or len(word) == 8:
 13 |   print("Your word is solid :)")
 12 |  elif len(word) == 9 or len(word) == 10:
 11 |   print("Your word is amazing...")
 10 |  elif len(word) == 11:
  9 |   print("Your word really amaze me... :) + You're so close to kaboom!!!")
  8 |  elif len(word) == 12:
  7 |   cprint(figlet_format('KABOOM!!!', font='smkeyboard'),
  6 |   |   |  'green', attrs=['bold'])
  5 |  else:
  4 |   print("U know rules? Try Again please!")
  3 |
  2 |  return word
  1
36  word_len(input("Type your word: "))
```

This is inside of usedDB file...

```
used_words_list = [""]
```

Is there many options to do this? Can someone explain me some of basics how to do this. I try a lot of diff ways but w/o success...

Comment: `used_words_list.append(word)`

Comment: Also, `elif len(word) == 6 or len(word) == 7 or len(word) == 8:` can be simplified to `elif len(word) in (6, 7, 8):` or `elif len(word) in range(6, 9):`

Comment: @BeRT2me I add used_words_list.append(word) and it shows -> NameError: name 'word' is not defined. Did you mean: 'ord'?

Comment: @KlemenHorvat-Novak where are you putting the line? It should be inside the word_len function.

Comment: with open("wordlog.txt" , "a") as f:    
         f.write(word + "\n")                 
         f.close()              ... how i can create statement inside there which depend if word len < 5 then dont store value otherwise if it's more save... @Command-Alt-Escape